# Testing a Log statement output in Golang

Tags: go, testing, logging

Hi I want to check that the output of a Log.error() is valid, I have this following code here

```
func logError(param bool)
bool {
    if (param == true)
        log.Error(fmt.Sprintf("I need to somehow tst, that the output here is correct"))

    return param;
}
```

I am not allowed to **modify** my existing code, I just want to ensure that whatever is printed by the console by my logError function, is what I expect it to be.

Is this possible without modifying my existing code, thank you.

Comment: The answer depends on which log library you are using.

Comment: Apologies, I have just added my Log library.

Comment: The Log library I am using is https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus

Answer (score 3):

With `logrus`, you can capture the output of the logger in a test:

```
oldOut:=log.StandardLogger().Out // Save current log target
buf:=bytes.Buffer{}
log.SetOutput(&buf)
logError(true)
// Here, buf.String() should give you the log msg
log.SetOutput(oldOut) // Restore log target
```